# column names with differing levels of JSON data

Tags: r, json, dataframe

I'm trying to extract information from JSON objects key by key and keep encountering the following warning:

> "Warning: Outer names are only allowed for unnamed scalar atomic
> inputs"

When I use `bind_cols()`, in an attempt to produce a dataframe object, I find that many of the columns are renamed from "X" to "X...1."

Comment: Welcome to SO, Jennah Gosciak! Questions tend to do better when reproducible, including sample data, code used, and expected-vs-actual output. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for good discussions on this, including the use of `dput(.)` for sample data. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.